# How to test if a value exist in a hash?

Tags: perl

Let's say I have this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%x = ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
```

and I would like to know if the value 2 is a hash value in `%x`.

How is that done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Fundamentally, a hash is a data structure optimized for solving the converse question, knowing whether the *key* 2 is present.  But it's hard to judge without knowing, so let's assume that won't change.

Possibilities presented here will depend on:

- how often you need to do it
- how dynamic the hash is

### One-time op

- `grep $_==2, values %x` (also spelled `grep {$_==1} values %x`) will return a list of as many 2s as are present in the hash, or, in scalar context, the number of matches.  Evaluated as a boolean in a condition, it yields just what you want.
  [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) works on versions of Perl as old as I can remember.
- `use List::Util qw(first); first {$_==2} values %x` returns only the first match, `undef` if none.  That makes it faster, as it will short-circuit (stop examining elements) as soon as it succeeds.  This isn't a problem for 2, but take care that the returned element doesn't necessarily evaluate to boolean true.  Use `defined` in those cases.
  [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#first-BLOCK-LIST) is a part of the Perl core since 5.8.
- `use List::MoreUtils qw(any); any {$_==2} values %x` returns exactly the information you requested as a boolean, and exhibits the short-circuiting behavior.
  [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) is available from CPAN.
- `2 ~~ [values %x]` returns exactly the information you requested as a boolean, and exhibits the short-circuiting behavior.
  [Smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) is available in Perl since 5.10.

### Repeated op, static hash

Construct a hash that maps values to keys, and use that one as a natural hash to test key existence.

```
my %r = reverse %x;
if ( exists $r{2} ) { ... }
```

### Repeated op, dynamic hash

Use a reverse lookup as above.  You'll need to keep it up to date, which is left as an exercise to the reader/editor.  (hint: value collisions are tricky)

Answer (score 10):

Shorter answer using smart match (Perl version 5.10 or later):

```
print 2 ~~ [values %x];
```

Comment: Please note in your answer that this is 5.10+ only

Answer (score 9):

```
my %reverse = reverse %x;
if( defined( $reverse{2} ) ) {
  print "2 is a value in the hash!\n";
}
```

If you want to find out the keys for which the value is 2:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %x ) {
  print "2 is the value for $key\n" if $x{$key} == 2;
}
```

Comment: This is a good plan if you need to do a lot of reverse lookups.  But for just one reverse lookup, it's overkill.

Answer (score 7):

Everyone's answer so far was not performance-driven. While the smart-match (`~~`) solution short circuits (e.g. stops searching when something is found), the `grep` ones do not.

Therefore, here's a solution which may have better performance for Perl before 5.10 that doesn't have smart match operator:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
if (any { $_ == 2 } values %x) {
    print "Found!\n";
}
```

Please note that this is just a specific example of searching in a list (`values %x`) in this case and as such, if you care about performance, the standard performance analysis of searching in a list apply as [discussed in detail in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678195/binary-search-in-an-array-in-perl/4679652#4679652)

Answer (score 5):

[grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html)

```
my %x = ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3); 

if (grep { $_ == 2 } values %x ) {
    print "2 is in hash\n";
}
else {
    print "2 is not in hash\n";
}
```

See also: `perldoc -q hash`

Answer (score 4):

Where $count would be the result:

```
my $count = grep { $_ == 2 } values %x;
```

This will not only show you if it's a value in the hash, but how many times it occurs as a value. Alternatively you can do it like this as well:

```
my $count = grep {/2/} values %x;
```