# How can I find a value in a Perl hash?

Tags: perl, hash

Is there any way in Perl to check if a value exists in a hash regardless of the key? I was reading up online and understand how to check for a key, but not for values.

For example, I would like to know if the string "apple" exists as a value for ANY keys in a hash. This is for a single level hash, not nested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a value exist in a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697075/how-to-test-if-a-value-exist-in-a-hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick hack ;-)

```
# string to search for
$value = "hugo"
%myHash = .....

@hashValues = values %myHash;

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @hashValues;
if(exists($hash{$value})) { ........ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `values` ?

You can find a specific value in a hash by iterating on hash values.

```
for(values %your_hash){
    ...
    if ($_ eq your_value){
        do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use `grep` with `values`

```
$value = "hugo"
%myHash = .....
if (grep {$_ eq $value} values %myHash) {
    print "$value found\n";
} else {
    print "$value not found\n";
}
```