# Wrapper for invoking perl

Tags: perl

How do I invoke perl using a wrapper kind of script so that migarting to a newer version of perl does not affect existing scripts?

Comment: You could install to a different directory? I'm assuming your current scripts start with a `#!/absolute/path/to/perl`

Comment: If you invoke your scripts with simply `perl`, wouldn't your shell automatically run whatever is first in your $PATH? why do you think you would run into issues after you upgrade?

Comment: What I want to do is to invoke the script without the shebang line i.e. the shebang line is in a separate script and all the other scripts invoke perl by calling it?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is the scenario you envision?

That you have a "perl" binary which you may change from Perl 5.8 to say 5.10?

The easiest solution to that is to have your shebang line point to a version-specific Perl.

There are two flavors of this approach - one has the version-specific softlink, one has a "current Production version of Perl" one.

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/perl5.8/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl5.8
$ ln -s /usr/local/perl5.8/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/current/perl

$ cat my_script.pl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8
# This script is REALLY hard coded to 5.8
...

$ cat my_script2.pl
#!/usr/local/bin/current/perl
# This script is hard coded to 5.8 for now, 
# but can be easily switched to different Perl version as part of MASS migration when ready
...
```

This way, your script is ALWAYS guaranteed to use Perl 5.8, even if you eventually upgrade to 5.12 and "perl" binary will start calling perl 5.12 as far as PATH goes.

This approach ALSO makes upgrading easier - simply change the softlink to point to new Perl binary when you wish.

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful. Is there some other way of doing it by invoking the script without the shebang line i.e. the shebang line is in a separate script and all the other scripts invoke perl by calling it?

Comment: @CMS - no, shebang line can't be separate from the script

Comment: What is PERL5LIB? Can I set that in a seperate script and call that script in other scripts? Thanks.

Comment: @CMS - eh? this answer doesn't mention PERL5LIB. And your last comment should be a separate SO question - too complicated for a  comment explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that backwards-compatibility for documented features will be broken in perl 5.

An insurance would be keeping a copy of the old perl binaries.

Comment: Somewhere between 5.8 and 5.10 was deprecated -C on shebang line. I got broken code because of it. Never say never ;)

Comment: @wk: You're right, I hadn't heard about that. Anyway, that's why I didn't write never :)

Comment: And I found my 5.8->5.10 gotcha too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045467/perl-match-outside-if-doesnt-reset-1-on-loop

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear which of these you want, but:

- If you **DO** want to always run the first `perl` in `$PATH`, so that you'll get upgraded versions transparently, you should use `#!/usr/bin/env perl`
- If you **DO NOT** want the version you're running to change out from under you, you can install exactly the `perl` you want at a location *other than* `/usr/bin/perl` (since that's managed by your OS vendor, not by you, so it could change when you don't want or expect it to) and start your Perl with `#!/path/to/my/custom/perl`
- In the latter case, you could still use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` and manipulate your `$PATH` so that the `perl` you want to use will be the first one found.  This is handy if you want to use different builds of `perl` at different times, such as for testing against different versions.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env perl` was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!