# Retrieve a particular return value in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a one-liner that lets me grab the second return value from a subroutine.

Rather than this:

```
($a,$b)=function;
print $b
```

It should be possible to do something like this

```
print ??? function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
sub test { return (1,2) }
print ((test)[1]);  # Returns 2
```

This also works:

```
print +(func())[1], "\n";
```

Comment: `print((function)[1])` or `print +(function)[1]` to get the precedence right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055519/.

Comment: ah, i was missing the parens.

Comment: @Steven -- yea, me too when I was playing with it. Need the parens around the [], which seems strange to me.

Comment: @jr: that's because (some of) the parens aren't just for precedence like they usually are, they are part of the `(LIST)[LIST]` list slice operator, and then you need other parens or a leading + to let perl know the list slice parens aren't just parens enclosing print's parameters.

Comment: Also possible (less efficiently) with an array slice operator: `print [function()]->[1]`.  Or `print pop @{[function()]}`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that function() returns a list, then using a slice like the poster above suggested works just fine.  If it returns an array reference, then you need to access it appropriately, for instance (@{function()})[1] to dereference the aref and then slice it.

Comment: why slice the array? Why not just `function()->[1]` to get the element?