# Use of uninitialized value $1 in addition - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a program that somewhat mimics the last command in UNIX, and I am trying to use backreferencing in my solution. My program does exactly what it is supposed to do but I get a run time error/warning. My question is why is this error/warning coming up and how can I fix an issue like this?

If you need more information I can provide.

Program Execution

```
./last dodoherty
```

OUTPUT

```
Here is a listing of the logins for dodoherty:

1. dodohert pts/1        pc-618-012.omhq. Wed Feb  8 09:19   still logged in
2. dodohert pts/6        ip98-168-203-118 Tue Feb  7 19:19 - 20:50  (01:31)
3. dodohert pts/3        137.48.207.178   Tue Feb  7 14:00 - 15:06  (01:05)
4. dodohert pts/1        137.48.219.250   Tue Feb  7 12:32 - 12:36  (00:04)
5. dodohert pts/21       137.48.207.237   Tue Feb  7 12:07 - 12:23  (00:16)
6. dodohert pts/11       ip98-168-203-118 Mon Feb  6 20:50 - 23:29  (02:39)
7. dodohert pts/9        ip98-168-203-118 Mon Feb  6 20:31 - 22:57  (02:26)
8. dodohert pts/5        pc-618-012.omhq. Fri Feb  3 10:24 - 10:30  (00:05)
Use of uninitialized value $1 in addition (+) at ./odoherty_last.pl line 43.
Use of uninitialized value $2 in addition (+) at ./odoherty_last.pl line 44.
Here is a summary of the time spent on the system for dodoherty:

dodoherty
8
8:6
```

The Code (Snippet of where the error is coming from, Also this is the only time $1 and $2 are used.)

```
foreach my $line2 (@user)
{
        $line2 =~ /\S*\((\d{2,2})\:(\d{2,2})\)\s*/;
        $hours = $hours + $1;
        $mins = $mins + $2;

        if( $mins >= 60 )
        {
                $hours = $hours + 1;
                $mins = $mins - 60;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define $1 and $2?

Comment: @Pluckerpluck `$1` and `$2` are not regular variables, they are read-only variables which contain the matches of the capturing groups in the last successful regex.

Comment: You don't need to say `\d{2,2}`; you can just say `\d{2}`. Also your `$hours = $hours + $1` would be better written as `$hours += $1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem might be in the following line.

`1. dodohert pts/1        pc-618-012.omhq. Wed Feb  8 09:19   still logged in`

That is because nothing matches the pattern so $1 and $2 are undefined.

Comment: Wow, now that you mention that, that sounds like a very logical solution. I will fix this and report back!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I added made it into an if statement and I do not get the errors anymore. I know it was a very simple problem but this is my first perl/regex program and I thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

As has been noted in other answers, your regex does not match, and therefore `$1` and `$2` are undefined. It is necessary to always check to make sure the appropriate regex matches before using these variables.

Below I have upgraded your script with some proper perl code. `+=` and `%=` are handy operator in this case. You can read about them in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Your regex uses `\S*` and `\s*`, both of which are completely unnecessary here, since your regex is not anchored to anything else. In other words, `\S*foo\s*` will match any string that contains `foo`, since it can match the empty string around `foo`. Also, `{2,2}` means "match at least 2 times, max 2", which in effect is the same as `{2}` "match 2 times".

You will see that I changed your math around, and that is because it assumes that `$mins` will never be higher than 120. I suppose technically, that is a safe assumption, but doing it like below, it can handle all values of minutes and successfully turn them into hours.

The script below is for demonstration. If you remove `DATA` and leave `<>`, you can use this script as-is like so:

```
last user | perl script.pl
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # required for say()

my ($hours, $mins);

while (<DATA>) {   # replace with while (<>) for live usage
    if (/\((\d{2})\:(\d{2})\)/) {
        $hours += $1;
        $mins  += $2;
        if( $mins >= 60 ) {
            $hours += int ($mins / 60);  # take integer part of division
            $mins  %= 60;                # remove excess minutes
        }
    }
}

say "Hours: $hours";
say "Mins : $mins";

__DATA__
1. dodohert pts/1        pc-618-012.omhq. Wed Feb  8 09:19   still logged in
2. dodohert pts/6        ip98-168-203-118 Tue Feb  7 19:19 - 20:50  (01:31)
3. dodohert pts/3        137.48.207.178   Tue Feb  7 14:00 - 15:06  (01:05)
4. dodohert pts/1        137.48.219.250   Tue Feb  7 12:32 - 12:36  (00:04)
5. dodohert pts/21       137.48.207.237   Tue Feb  7 12:07 - 12:23  (00:16)
6. dodohert pts/11       ip98-168-203-118 Mon Feb  6 20:50 - 23:29  (02:39)
7. dodohert pts/9        ip98-168-203-118 Mon Feb  6 20:31 - 22:57  (02:26)
8. dodohert pts/5        pc-618-012.omhq. Fri Feb  3 10:24 - 10:30  (00:05)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it was very helpful (Would upvote but I need 15 rep XD) I will take all your suggestions into consideration in latter parts of the class.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my $hours = 0;
my $mins  = 0;
my $loggedIn = 0;
while (<STDIN>)
{
        chomp;
        if (/\S*\((\d{2,2})\:(\d{2,2})\)\s*/)
        {
            $hours = $hours + $1;
            $mins  = $mins + $2;
            if($mins >= 60 )
            {
                $hours = $hours + 1;
                $mins = $mins - 60;
            }
        }
        elsif (/still logged in$/)
        {
            $loggedIn = 1;
        }
}

print "Summary: $hours:$mins ", ($loggedIn) ? " (Currently logged in)" : "", "\n";
```

Comment: I agree, always wrap pattern matches in an `if`, for more than one reason. Another can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045467/perl-match-outside-if-doesnt-reset-1-on-loop

Comment: Initializing `$hours,$mins,$isloggedIn` is not required if you use `+=` instead (to avoid a warning). `chomp` is not required, as end of line is never used.

Answer (score 2):

When ever your RE fails to match, $1 and $2 have no value.

For this reason, it's considered best practice on ever to use $1, $2 etc. inside a conditional which tests the success of the RE.

So don't do:

```
$string =~ m/(somepattern)/sx;
my $var = $1;
```

But instead to do something like:

```
my $var = 'some_default_value';
if($string =~ m/(somepattern)/sx){
  $var = $1;
}
```